# Analytic function on intersection of two open sets

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

We are given two open subsets $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ both open and convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

if $f_1$ and $f_2$ are (real) analytic in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$.

Show that $f_1=f_2$ in $\Omega_1\cap\Omega_2$ if all the derivatives of $f_1$ and $f_2$ coincide at atleast one point $y \in \Omega_1\cap \Omega_2$.

I know that the analytic functions are uniquely defined if all derivatives of function are known at one point in Open and connected set.

My question is where do I use the convexity?

I am also asked to give a counter example where the result fails if sets are not convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. The intersection of convex sets is convex (and hence, connected). For a counterexample take two open, connected sets with a disconnected intersection.